# Choosing between two reliable, yet contradictory fatwas based on desire: is this a major sin?

Tags: fatwa

I once read that if one stands between two fatwas that both have evidence for their claims, and chooses the fatwa based on desire, then this is the worst of the major sins (which indicates that it'll be worse than shirk).

Having to choose an option between two reliable fatwas that both have strong evidence, why would it be haram to follow the fatwa you feel comfortable with or desire? Should I always instead choose the fatwa I don’t like regardless the evidence?

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn more about how this site works. Thanks for the question.

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are referring to: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/229013 ?

Comment: A fatwa in first place is not binding as it is like a juridical advice. Only a qadi (judge) can -and has the power and means to- speak out a binding verdict. Nevertheless if somebody does something despite knowing it is haram it is certainly sinful. It is also sinful to follow your desires and hawa.

Comment: Not an answer to my question. I am afraid that you didn’t understand. Having to choose an option between two reliable fatwas that both have strong evidence, why would it be haram to follow the fatwa you feel comfortable with or desire? Should I always instead choose the fatwa I don’t like regardless the evidence?

Comment: I tried my best to turn this into an answerable question.  Hopefully it's consistent with your intention.